# Jquery Animate - trigger function mid way through animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to trigger a function mid way through an animation?

The animation includes a solid block which swipes over an image from top to bottom - I would like to trigger a function at the point that the image is completely covered and remove the image from the html (mid way through the animation)

My current function is -

```
    function animateCover() {
    $('#cover').animate({ bottom: '1400px'}, 4000, function() { });
}
```

The image is completely covered at 800px point - can I access this property to trigger a function?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since there isn't a tick counter in jQuery, you need to "emulate" it:

```
function animateCover() {
  var  
      $cover = $('#cover'),
      interval = setInterval(function(){
        if ($cover.is(':animated')){
          if (parseInt($cover.css('bottom')) > 800){
             alert('trigger');
             clearInterval(interval);
          }
        } else {
         clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 13); // 13 is the minimum possible in Javascript 

  $cover.animate({ bottom: '1400px'}, 4000, function() { $cover.text('done'); });
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/emV4p/1/

Comment: _13 is the minimum possible in Javascript_ ??

Comment: yes, the minimum interval possible in javascript. some browsers allow you to go down to 8 though... check this http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/Minimum-Timer-Intervals-in-JavaScript some browsers even force it to be higher for performance reasons

Answer (score 0):

What about splitting the animation into 2.

```
function animateCover() {
    $('#cover').animate({ bottom: '700px'}, 2000, function() {
        $('#imgID').hide();
        $('#cover').animate({ bottom: '1400px'}, 2000 );
    });
}
```

Comment: Cheers Bruno - works great but it causes a pause in the animation though - client wants a continuous swipe.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**: Here's a perfectly working solution with minimal code-

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4SFwe/4/)

jQuery-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $("#image").css('background-image','none');
    },2000);
  $("#block").animate({
    bottom:'400px'
  },3000);
});
```

Comment: Hi - thanks very much for your help - I need a continuous animation though - this pauses midway through